# Delete specific words from a string of texts in Excel

Tags: excel, function, words

I'm looking for a way to remove unnecessary information (like prepositions) from a column of texts. E.g. "The", "and", "is", etc. Each cell has information like product description or feedback, etc. So it's like a paragraph in each cell.

Find and Replace function will remove the words even if they are characters within a text. E.g. Remove "the" and "these" will become "se". Don't want that. Substitute function doesn't work either.

Is there any function or formula that can help with this?

Comment: Try to replace like " the " i.e. add a leading and trailing spaces with the prepositions without the double quotes as I showed in the example.

Comment: If you can use VBA, you can utilize the Regular Expression engine.  That includes tokens for the word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the column of texts in column A,

Use a different sheet (sheet 4 in this example), to have the list of words that you want to remove from the column of texts. You have to have the list in `A1`, `B1`, `C1` and so on.

Then use the below formula in column B of your master sheet,

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,Sheet4!A$1&" ","")`

Now you have to drag this formula to the right. If you have totally 4 words in sheet4 , then you have to drag the formula for 4 columns towards right. The last column will have the final texts with these words removed. Once you drag them, double click the fill handle to complete the formulas for the entire list. Let me know for any doubts. You could then hide the columns which are not required to view.